Is there a formal definition of when an algorithm is a brute force algorithm?
This is similar to a previous question I asked, here: Is there a formal definition of when an algorithm is greedy?. I now want to know whether anyone has formalized the notion of a brute force algorithm. If so, I would like to see such a definition. But perhaps this is, again, a notion which is not amenable to formalization.

Intuitively, the same algorithm can be "brute force" or not depending on how you describe the problem it solves. Every algorithm is "brute force" for the problem of doing exactly what its code says.

It seems to me that an algorithm is brute force over a search space $S$ with respect to some evaluation $f$ if it computes $f(s)$ for each $s\in S$, at least in the worst case (there exists some input such that it does every computation).
For example:

A brute force algorithm for finding $\min f(s)$ or $\max f(s)$ calculates $f(s)$ for every $s\in S$ and records $f(s)$ if it is the least/greatest value seen so far.
For $\arg\min f(s)$ or $\arg\max f(s)$ it does the same but records $s$.
In the case of finding some value that satisfies some set of criteria we can interpret $f:S\to \{0,1\}$ as a boolean and if $f(s)=1$ is seen the algorithm might terminate early.


I think the answer will depend on how you define an algorithm in precise terms, but here's a possibility. Let $A$ be an algorithm that operates on ordered sets $(S,\pi)$, verifies or negates the truth of some statement $(\exists s \in S)\phi(s)$ where $\phi$ is a quantifier-free formula, takes $N_{S,\pi}$ steps to finish (maybe think of a Turing machine) for the whole ordered set, and $N_s$ to finish when checking the singleton set $\{s\}$. Let $\neg_{\phi}(S)$ be those $s \in S$ where $\neg \phi(s)$ holds. Then $A$ is brute force if for all $S$ there exists some $\pi$ such that:
$$N_{S,\pi} \geq \sum_{s \in \neg_{\phi}S}N_{s} + \max_{s \notin \neg_{\phi}S}N_s,$$
in other words, the algorithm takes at least as long as the worst-case computation time of an "intuitive" brute force algorithm.
